# How to downgrade xamarin.android to 9.0.0.20?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

After updating the visual studio to version7.7(build 1868)and xamarin.android to Version: 9.1.0.38 getting compilation errors.

I need to downgrade the xamarin.android version to the previous 9.0.0.20. I am not able to find the download for this particular version.
Can somebody please provide me the link to the download. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you still using Xamarin studio in the first place it got deprecated a year ago or so!! You should use `Visual Studio for Mac` or `Xamarin for Visual Studio` respectively

Comment: Please add the respective errors you are running into as they may not be specific to a release.

Comment: Hi @G.hakim I am using Visual studio community(for mac) only. I just upgraded the visual studio to the latest and other packages for xamarin.android and ios then getting the errors. It was working fine on previous version.

Comment: Hi @JonDouglas I am getting errors in my android project in all the xml files where i have used custom views.
Error XA1002: We found a matching key 'OnTrack.Droid.Widgets.CiPencilEditText' for 'Ontrack.Droid.Widgets.CiPencilEditText'. But the casing was incorrect. Please correct the casing (XA1002) (OnTrack.Droid)

Comment: I don't think your issue has something to do with updating xamarin i think you have recently changed the namespace or something of that sort which is causing this

Comment: Hi @G.hakim i haven't changed anything in my namespace. same working project got messed up just after upgrade

Comment: Well then give us the full log so, I  can raise a bug at Xamarin for the same.

Comment: I have fixed all the issues related to namespace but it's still failing while building project.
packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.11/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(3,3): Error MSB4062: The "Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs" task could not be loaded from the assembly packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.11/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.dll.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. (MSB4062)